# Whats the equivalent of JPanel in JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, javafx

I'm still learning and experimenting with **GUI**s in **JavaFX** and I cant seem to get the "look" that I'm aiming for.. I'm trying to group a couple of **Labels** in a **Panel** and then in a **different panel** add another **Label**. But I cant seem to figure out how to properly use **"JPanels"** in **JavaFX**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D
Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here is what I'm trying to achieve by trying different layouts, no luck still

[image: preview]

Comment: See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I edited the question to include the image that was hosted at the fast-files link.  As you get more reputation, you will also be able to include images inline.  In the meantime, please don't link to fast-files again: that site was super-annoying.  I also suggest you download [SceneBuilder from Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/) and try creating your UI layout using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While Java FX [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) is similar to Swing [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), the example below uses subclasses of `Pane` to get various layout effects. In particular,

- Instead of a `JPanel` set to `GridLayout`, use `GridPane`.
- Instead of a `JPanel` set to `BoderLayout`, use `BorderPane`.
- Use `ContentDisplay.TOP` to position a label's content above its text, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22609672/230513).
- Use `ContentDisplay.CENTER` for `topCenter` to make the label overlay the rectangle; for comparison, a previous [version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37935114/1) used `StackPane`.
- Use `setPadding()`, `setMargin()` and `setVgap()` to spread things out a little.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37935114/230513
 */
public class BorderTest extends Application {

    private static final Border black = new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK,
        BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, new CornerRadii(8), new BorderWidths(2)));
    private static final Border red = new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.RED,
        BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, new CornerRadii(8), new BorderWidths(2)));
    private static final Border blue = new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLUE,
        BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, new CornerRadii(8), new BorderWidths(2)));
    private static final Color yellow = Color.YELLOW.deriveColor(0, .9, 1, 1);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(16));
        root.setVgap(16);
        root.setBorder(black);
        root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
            Color.LIGHTGRAY, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        BorderPane top = new BorderPane();
        top.setPadding(new Insets(16));
        top.setBorder(red);
        top.setLeft(createLabel("Label 1", yellow, 16));
        Label topCenter = createLabel("Label 2", yellow, 64);
        topCenter.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(topCenter, new Insets(16));
        top.setCenter(topCenter);
        top.setRight(createLabel("Label 3", yellow, 16));
        root.add(top, 0, 0);

        BorderPane bot = new BorderPane();
        bot.setPadding(new Insets(16));
        bot.setBorder(blue);
        bot.setCenter(createLabel("Label 4", Color.GREEN, 24));
        root.add(bot, 0, 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Label createLabel(String text, Color color, int size) {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(3 * size, 2 * size);
        r.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        r.setStroke(color);
        r.setStrokeWidth(3);
        Label l = new Label(text, r);
        l.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);
        l.setTextFill(color);
        l.setFont(new Font(16));
        return l;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I've learned much from playing around and experimenting with your Example! But I do have a small question, How do i go about getting the **Height** or **Width** of the Top **BorderPane** for example? 
_(top.getWidth())_

Comment: @user6408978: kudos for experimenting; check again _after_ `show()`, but ask yourself why you need to know; add an instance of `ColumnConstraints` with `setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS)`, as shown in the API, to see the effect.

Answer (score 2):

The `JavaFX` equivalent to a `JPanel` is a [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can have some very nice tutorials http://java2s.com/ about javaFX and many many more.JavaFX equivalent to `JPanel` is [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) and an example:(taken from http://zetcode.com/gui/javafx/layoutpanes/)

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * ZetCode JavaFX tutorial
 *
 * This program positions three shapes
 * using absolute coordinates.
 *
 * Author: Jan Bodnar
 * Website: zetcode.com
 * Last modified: June 2015
 */

public class AbsoluteLayoutEx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        initUI(stage);
    }

    private void initUI(Stage stage) {

        Pane root = new Pane();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(25, 25, 50, 50);
        rect.setFill(Color.CADETBLUE);

        Line line = new Line(90, 40, 230, 40);
        line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        Circle circle = new Circle(130, 130, 30);
        circle.setFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);

        root.getChildren().addAll(rect, line, circle);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 220, Color.WHITESMOKE);

        stage.setTitle("Absolute layout");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```